# I can't access the image source from local network. i used codeigniter framework

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

```
<img src="file://url/RTMIImages/RTMI00025082/Images/340113_LSTIRES_1LI_IN_20140916_181953.jpg">
```

I used Codeigniter framework the above code does not show me any images in browser but when i inspect element and click the image source then the image is show me in browser in next tab.this image is also show in simple html file and acccesed but not in codeigniter. any idea plz share.

Comment: You have to write the source from the server document root! This what you have now is the file in the browser but not over the server! So thats why your server doesn't find the file but the file itself in the filesystem exists

Comment: check Replace `file` with `http`

Comment: i replace file with http but still have problem

Comment: This might happen cache problem also, clear data and browser cache and try again.

Comment: Is the HTML that contains this code also loaded using the `file` protocol, or do you use a web server?

Comment: @Rizier123 how to write the source from the server document root to access the image my code is given above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi @waqas it works like a rocket

```
   $url = "\\\\XXX.XXX.XX.XX\\folderPath\\imagename.jpg";
                $imageData = base64_encode(file_get_contents($url));
                $src       = 'data: '.mime_content_type($url).';base64,'.$imageData;
                echo '<img src="',$src,'">';
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<img src="\\10.10.10.49\RTMIImages\RTMI00025082\Images\340113_LSTIRES_1LI_IN_20140916_181953.jpg">
```

instead of

```
<img src="file://10.10.10.49/RTMIImages/RTMI00025082/Images/340113_LSTIRES_1LI_IN_20140916_181953.jpg">
```

Comment: i used codigniter frame work still not show any image.

Answer (score 0):

This works fine. Here is my code for a sample view containing link to an image in my localhost directory.

Controller file `image`:

```
<?php

class Image extends CI_Controller {



function index() {
    $filename = 'crop.jpeg';
    $gallery_path_url = 'http://localhost/ci/images/';
    $data['image_url'] = $gallery_path_url . $filename;
    $this->load->view('home_image_view', $data);
    }
}
?>
```

View File `home_image_view.php`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>home</title>

</head>
<body>
    Some head note.
    <img src="<?php echo $image_url; ?>">
    Some end note.
</body>

</html>
```

To visit the page. go to `http://localhost/<sub folder name>/index.php/image`

Comment: the file source comes correctly when i inspect element then click on this url the image shows me in next tab but it not show me in the codeigniter view. Is codigniter have some setting to get data from local networks?

Comment: I have edited the answer (see body tag in view for changes) Check if this solves your problem. Note: you can add css to <img> for proper display. Hope this helps now.

Comment: i try the code in simple html file the image comes correct but in codeigniter not comes any reason

Comment: any other suggetion kindly help.

Comment: i test it actullay my server not getting the image data is there any config for this

Comment: I know the page is not showing you any image. I am asking what it shows!? else, just  post the page source here.

Comment: not showing any thing in image section just blank space

Comment: care to post the page source? I can't understand like this.